# hadoop 2.9.1 failed to start DataNode

Tags: hadoop, alpine-linux

I'm new with Apache Hadoop and I'm trying to install in Alpine (docker container) in pseudo-distribuited mode Apache Hadoop 2.9.1 but I got this error when I run start-dfs.sh

```
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 131: 883 Aborted  (core dumped) nohup nice -n $HADOOP_NICENESS $hdfsScript --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR $command "$@" > "$log" 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

The NameNode and SecondaryNameNode start succesfully but the DataNode no.

Comment: I don't think Alpine/ASH shell is officially supported in Hadoop

Comment: Yes you're right, but I installed bash and I'm using it to run hadoop

Comment: I don't think the shell is the only problem. For example, Hadoop (particularly, the Datanode) has native C libraries (libhdfs and libsnappy, for example) that are used, which might depend on musl libc

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and also every version >2.9.1 ended in a quick core dump of a the DataNode in Docker.

The comment from [@OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585660/hadoop-2-9-1-failed-to-start-datanode#comment126548231_71585660) actually lead me to the right direction which should have been an acceptable answer - so here is a quick heads up for future users:

Apparently, components of the DataNode won't work well with Alpine/Musl and switching to e.g. an Ubuntu-based parent image like [8-jdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin) solves this problem.

Here is a link to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/unexist/showcase-hadoop-cdc-quarkus/blob/master/podman/hadoop/Dockerfile) I am currently using.